# Is voting up comments a privilege?

Tags: support, comments, privileges, comment-voting

..and if so, what is the requirement?

I couldn't see it listed on `/privileges`, particularly on `/privileges/comment` which seemed the most likely candidate, and I couldn't find any other posts here on meta...

Answer (score 5):

> Comments are meant as a lightweight way to expand, clarify, and discuss questions and answers. They can be upvoted (but not downvoted) and flagged, but do not generate reputation.

I would assume that because the above blurb from the [comment privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) mentions voting, that you can vote on comments when you can comment. Since comment votes are intended to reduce "+1 good point" type comments this assumption makes sense, but I don't know for sure.

The page doesn't mention that you can vote on comments, but it doesn't mention that you can comment either. The privilege pages really just describe functionality and it's just the link that describes what you can do. Maybe "comment everywhere" should be changed to "use comments everywhere"?

Comment: Makes sense. Though I think the privilege of upvoting should probably be explicitly stated there, just for clarity.

Comment: I can't confirm "vote on comments when you can comment". I have, at this particular time, reputation 3 badge 1, but I can comment this comment, edit this comment, delete this comment and at the same time cannot vote on any comments here.. _<irony> Actually I'm a filthy reputation-and-badges-rich dinosaur user but unfortunately lost all my reputation and badges (leaving me with 3 1) in a cyber burglary </irony>_

Answer (score 0):

If we can treat the FAQ remarks as general:

**Do I have to log in or create an account ?**

> You can ask questions, answer, and suggest edits as an anonymous user, much like Wikipedia. There are some things you won’t be able to do on the site without registering, **such as vote**. But it’s easy to register if you'd like to; all you need is an OpenID.

It doesn't specifically mention comments, but it's a privilege reserved for registered users, and as pointed out in the comments (by the OP) it requires some reputation.

Comment: While that's certainly true, there's no particular reason to assume that refers specifically to votes on *comments*, rather than questions/answers.

Comment: @Cody Consequently, I don't see any reason to assume it refers specifically to votes on questions/answers, and not just all site votes in general.

Comment: it also doesn't say "In addition to logging in, you'll need 15 reputation to vote posts up, 125 reputation to vote posts down, and <insert whole point of question here> to vote for comments"

Comment: @Grace: Right, that's why I interpret it more generally. As Jon points out, various levels of reputation are required for various types of voting. The quoted statement seems overly generic, and doesn't address whether voting on comments is a privilege.

Comment: So, will this be an incentive to amend the FAQ?

Comment: I think the FAQ is okay; where this really needs to be added (if it doesn't exist already and we're all just overlooking it) is on the `/privileges` page to fit with the rest of the privileges.

Answer (score 0):

It *is* a privilege, but not a privilege distinct from normal flagging. Note that [the Vote up privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) mentions it:

> #### When should I vote up?
>
> Whenever you encounter a question, answer **or comment** that you feel is especially useful, vote it up!

(emphasis mine)

[As pydave notes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99001/is-voting-up-comments-a-privilege/99028#99028), the help page for the commenting privilege makes no mention of voting, so it should be assumed the ability to *vote on* comments is distinct from the ability to *create* them.